# "Properties" menu option is enabled for the components in "Team Artifacts" views

Tags: java, eclipse

"Properties" menu option is enabled for the components in "Team Artifacts" 
Other ALM applications have this feature disabled.
As I checked this is contributing it from "com.ibm.team.process.rcp.ui"
The default behavior for this should be disabled.
[image]

After adding the eclipse external tool feature (for beyond-compare) in my product, the properties popup menu /context menu on my Team Artifacts view is enabled.

**What should be the reason for causing the properties menu enablement?**

**Is there any way to disable properties menu as it in original?**

[image]

Comment: At a guess there were no properties pages defined for the entry before, and now there are pages defined.

Comment: yes the guess is right.. now the question is how to avoid or remove that property page from this view? aThere is an another view that needs that properties page..